# Creating view with a specific formula

Tags: email, view, selection, formula, lotus

I have a DB with thousands of E-mails and I want to make a selection / sorting of mails which I can copy - paste into another DB.

The arguments shall be:

- Sent by me
- Sent to different names f.ex. @ibm.com OR @google.com OR @facebook.com
- Which are NOT cc'ed to @myspace.com OR @kitchen.com
- Only sent mails, no sametime chats or Draft mails

I struggle to find a complete formula which cover everything.

Comment: I want to copy-paste a definite collection of E-mails to another DB belonging to a project which is open for several persons. Archiving is thus not a fix here.

Comment: SELECT (@Contains(Author; "peter")) & (@Contains(ToNames; "@ibm.com")) | (@Contains(ToNames; "@google.com")) & (!@Contains(CopyTo; "myspace.com")) | (!@Contains(CopyTo; "kitchen.com"))

Answer (score 2):

A selection formula consists of items beeing checked for content and operators to combine the different queries.

In addition there are @Functions to manipulate values to match your needs.

The sender of an email is in the `From`- item. Recipients can be found in `SendTo`, copy- recipients in `CopyTo`, etc. etc.

You can find out the item- names by using the property- window (Alt + Enter). On the second tab there are all items that are in a specific document.

To get all mails FROM you, you would write something like:

```
SELECT From = "CN=YourName/OU=YourOrg"
```

For the exact value -> Property- window

To get all mails sent to special domains it would be:

```
SELECT @Contains( SendTo ; "@yahoo.com" ) | @Contains( SendTo ; "@google.com" )
```

@Contains is one of the @Functions. Just google for it, to get a complete list. The [Designer Help](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTES_FORMULA_LANGUAGE.html) is a good reference. 
As @Formula- Language is very powerfull working with lists, the above example could also be written as:

```
SELECT @Contains( SendTo ; "@yahoo.com" : "@google.com" )
```

Colon is the list operator....

Logical operators are:
    | = OR
    & = AND
    ! = NOT

Take care: & has a higher precedence than |, if you want to change that, you need to use brackets to correct the precedence...

Maybe you need a "unifier" for your operations like `@Lowercase( ... )` or `@Uppercase` if there are different ways you wrote the addresses in your mail. A valid formula could look like:

```
SELECT Form = "Memo" : "Reply" & From = "CN=YourName/OU=YourOrg" & 
@Contains( @LowerCase( SendTo ) ; "@yahoo.com" : "@google.com" ) &
!@Contains( @LowerCase( CopyTo ; "@myspace.com" )
```

Feel free to modify it regarding to your needs

Using your example from the comment it would be:

```
SELECT (@Contains(From; "peter")) & 
(@Contains(SendTo; "@ibm.com")) | (@Contains(SendTo; "@google.com")) & 
!(@Contains(CopyTo; "myspace.com") | @Contains(CopyTo; "kitchen.com"))
```

Comment: I tried again with these formula but it will not work. Each of the three works i.e. From / ToNames / CopyTo but not all together. There must be a trick for how to nest the functions together as in Excel.     SELECT (@Contains(Author; "peter")) & (@Contains(ToNames; "@ibm.com")) | (@Contains(ToNames; "@google.com")) & (!@Contains(CopyTo; "myspace.com")) | (!@Contains(CopyTo; "kitchen.com"))

Comment: This is your formula with the right concatenation: `SELECT @Contains(Author; "peter") & 
@Contains(ToNames; "@ibm.com" :"@google.com") & 
!@Contains(CopyTo; "myspace.com" : "kitchen.com")` - In addition to Torsten's tips you have to consider that "&" has a higher priority then "|" - that is the main mistake in your formula. So, the long version of your formula would be: `SELECT @Contains(Author; "peter") & 
(@Contains(ToNames; "@ibm.com") | @Contains(ToNames; "@google.com")) &
!(@Contains(CopyTo; "myspace.com") | @Contains(CopyTo; "kitchen.com"))`

Comment: There is no item `ToNames` in Lotus Notes, and there is no (default) item `Author`... probably that's why the selection does not show anything... AND: `(!@Contains( CopyTo; "myspace.com" ) | !@Contains( CopyTo; "kitchen.com" )) will return true for any mail, that does not contain BOTH, "myspace.com" AND "kitchen.com"...

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't copy/paste... I'd use standard Notes archiving, with multiple formulas. No agents, no programming (except for the formulas), what else can one want?

Comment: I want to copy-paste a definite collection of E-mails to another DB belonging to a project which is open for several persons. Archiving is thus not a fix here.

Comment: And what if you enable full-text searching? Better be pragmatic if you have to do this only once. Finding the 'proper' way to do it strikes me as overcomplicating things.

Comment: I would appreciate an answer on to my defined request and not small "fixes" which are on side of what I asked for. Anyone out there knowing how to put together different field functions into the same "View selection". Sent by me + sent to selections + not copied to.